# How to set focus on next input in Jquery autocomplete item select

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I am using `jquery` autocomplete and not able to set focus on next input box after selecting the item from `jquery` autocomplete please help me out from this.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);

                        },

                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

If the next control to focus is

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtlocation" placeholder="Location" runat="server" Style="height: 30px;"
                                                class="span5"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Try `$('#txtSearch').next('input').focus();`

Comment: in which place i put this code ? @SyedAliTaqi

Comment: after `SearchText();`

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi not working i had tried

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `timeOut`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
SearchText();
setTimeout(function () {
$('#txtSearch').next('input').focus();
}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Still its not working when i put this code entire autocomplete is not working

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer,

You need an event called close for this purpose

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);

                        },

                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                },
              close: function (event, ui) {
                $('#txtlocation').focus();
              }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ocbta1k/1/

Comment: Try this after SearchText();

Comment: this code is not working , when the text which is not search in autocomplete is focused to next control but not for the item which is select is still focus on the same control :(

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? Is that the behavior you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should add setting focus to the select event like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);

                        },

                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#txtlocation').focus();
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    ($("#txtlocation")).focus();
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```